# Why can't I continue executing Julia code in the VSCode REPL if I hit CTRL+F5?

Tags: visual-studio-code, julia, read-eval-print-loop

Under Visual Studio Code (VSCode) with the Julia extension there are two REPLs. One is the standard REPL that comes with Julia. The other is some modified REPL provided by VSCode. This modified REPL has some advantages over the standard REPL.

I found two ways of running a program in the VSCode REPL. For both the first step is to select the file containing the code in the VSCode editor. The second step could be either one of these:

1. Hit CTRL+F5,
2. Click on an arrow (a triangle) that points rightwards and sits on the right-hand side of the bar with tabs at the top of the code editor.

Method 1 Is more convenient, especially since Method 2 sometimes does not work and has to be repeated.

However, there is a strong disadvantage to Method 1: After the program executes I get the message:

```
Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

After this I cannot execute code in the REPL since hitting any key indeed closes the Terminal.

This does not happen when the program is started by Method 2: after the program runs I can run Julia code in the Terminal.

Is there a way to have Method 1 work like Method 2?

---

Comment: You seem to jave strange shortcuts... it doesn't just run with SHIFT+Enter?

Comment: @Antonello - Ctrl+F5 and hitting the arrow are the standard ways of starting the VSCode REPL.

SHIFT+Enter with the cursor on the editor creates a new line below the current line and moves the cursor to the newly created line. No code is executed.

One can also select all code by hitting CTRL+A and then hit

Comment: One can also select all code in the editor window by hitting CTRL+A and then hit SHIFT+Enter. In that case all code in the editor window is erased and no code is executed.